# How to build accessible gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I'm working on a website, and I want to add gallery to it. But I have a problem - the gallery must be accessible to blind etc, and I have no idea how to do it.

Usually, in those kinds of galleries, I would do the html like this:

```
            <ul>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/1.jpg"></li>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/2.jpg"></li>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/3.jpg"></li>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/4.jpg"></li>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/5.jpg"></li>
                <li data-src="path/to/image/etc.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
```

and using css and jquery I would use the `data-src` and add it as a background to the `li` (because not all photos are squers, so I'll use `background-size: cover;`). Then, when user will click on the `li`, a popup will appear with the full size image.

There are some problems with that. For example, it must be clickable using `tab` in the keyboard. I can add `a` to the `li`, but is it ok not having href? And what the machine will "think" when it'll see empty `ul` list? Another problem is the popup. The html of the popup and it's `img` tag located at the bottom of the page, so the machine won't be able to see it immediately after click. Another problem is the `alt`. There won't be description to photos (because they aren't uploaded by me), so I'll leave the `alt` empty?

Thanks!

Comment: _There won't be description to photos_ you can't reasonably build an accessible gallery without that; what do you expect to serve to screen readers if you have no text?

Comment: @Mathletics Well, I can add the title of the page to the `alt`, but that's kind of cheating, it won't help to the blind people. What facebook does with photos?

Answer (score 1):

Principles:

1. Images that convey information must have a text description. Best practice is to always use am `<img>` for an informational image, however, you could also use a title attribute on the anchor around the image.
2. Everything must be keyboard operable. Anchors without an href will not be tab focusable, add `href="#"` to fix that problem.
3. Blind people are not the only keyboard users. Make sure that you can control the gallery with the keyboard only.
4. Manage the focus when dynamic content appears and disappears. Make sure that the focus goes onto the full size popup and that the "close" control is keyboard operable. When closed, focus should go back to the anchor that opened the image.
5. Controls should have the correct role. Links are used to go to different pages. Buttons are used to control things on the same page. Your "anchor" around the image is acting like a button so add `role="button"` to the anchor.

You will have to give the image uploaders a way to add the alt text for the images. Facebook is not a good example of accessibility - it is a bad example. Look at [EasyChirp](http://www.easychirp.com/) for a good example of how to do alts on images that are uploaded.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have made some changes: When the popup open, I did that you can use your arrows in the keyboard to move through photos, and close it using `esc`. The arrows themselves (the html ones) aren't accessible using the keyboard. In the `li` list I've added `a` and inside it I've placed the alt of the photo (as pure text with font size 0). This area is still uses background and not `img` because I had to use `background-size: cover;`. Is all of those are OK and enough?

Comment: The arrows need to be accessible to the keyboard. How is a user supposed to discover that the arrow keys do the same as the arrow buttons? If a user is sighted, they will be able to see the arrows, but not get to them with the keyboard. This can be frustrating and lead to inability to use the page. There is a principle that you must adhere to: everything you can interact with using the mouse or touch, must be able to be interacted with using the keyboard. Embrace it, don't avoid it!